# Comparison of 1G123 to 4538

Tags: timing, monostable, edge

I am designing the edge detection circuit with predefined output pulse duration. Pulse width will be 18.33 ms, supply power is 5V. Error tolerable is +-1 ms.

There're a number of designs already available. Initially I focused on [4538](https://www.uni-kl.de/elektronik-lager/418169), called "dual precision monostable". I do not need dual, and datasheet is dated back 1988, and I decided to look for something more recent.

I found [SN74LVC1G123](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74lvc1g123.pdf), which is declared to work at 5V properly, but I see several things I can not properly evaluate:

1. 4538 is described as "precision", 1G123 does not have this word in it. Logical suspicion - newer device is not precise?
2. 4538 says - use simple formula T=R*C. Great. 1G123 does not give any formula at all, gives plots instead where I am expected to find the matching values. Reading 4538 datasheet more thoroughly I see it talks about error depending on the temperature and supply voltage. So I assume that these datasheets just take different approach with 4538 deliberately making things looking simpler than they are.
3. I need 18.33 ms (1.833*10^7 ns) at 5V, looking at 1G123 datasheet plots in section 9.2.3 I do not think I will be able to select capacitance properly at the first try. Am I expected to experiment here and find suitable capacitance?

And in overall, do I take proper approach? Is the component type I select a proper one?

I am a gidital guy, and for me it would be much simpler to have CPLD with high speed clock in and some logic inside. But there're no CPLDs with just few inputs and outputs, and they must cost more than 4538 or 1G123 (however this one is questionable).

To give more detail on what I want to achieve in general: I need to detect video synchronization frequency automatically - 50 Hz or 60 Hz, and for this I set timer at 18.3 ms (midpoint between 50/60) and sample the value at the next edge: process not finished means 50 Hz (PAL), and finished is 60 Hz (NTSC). I did not find any dedicated device to give this task to.

Comment: After looking at the datasheets, in my opinion the CD4538 and SN74LVC1G123 use a very similar principle for their timing function. A capacitor is (dis)charged via a resistor from the supply, how long that takes is timed. If you use sufficiently accurate components for the timing R and C you should get accurate timings. It might be a challenge to get that timing correct over temperature. For a (couple of) prototype(s) I'd add a variable resistor and hand-trim the timing. If this is for mass production you need to do some calculations for the statistics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A CPLD would be the wrong tool for the job. At this time scale, a microcontroller is much more appropriate. Even a tiny [PIC10F200](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/40001239F.pdf) running on its ±2% internal oscillator would have enough precision for your application. You can get one in an SOT23-6 package for less than 50 cents, and the only external component required is a bypass capacitor.

Comment: Exactly! Right now looking at datasheet of 10f200, it has 8 bit timer with prescaler.

Answer (score 1):

The speed is very low, you can do that with a microcontroller with only a decoupling capacitor like [pic10F322](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/40001585D.pdf), the internal oscillator is calibrated to 1% which is enough for your needs and it has a timer and prescaller that can be used for timings.

If it's a one time project I would suggest using the cheapest Arduino and Arduino IDE that is much beginner friendly.